# Getting a Seg Fault with an iostream and pointers

Tags: c++

I am trying to read in a data file (a maze), of which I seem to have coded myself a seg fault, I admit that I was sick for the lecture in my college about dynamic allocation, and have searched for my issue throughly, to no avail.
 Here is my snippet of code:

```
void MazeClass::ReadMaze(ifstream& mazedata) {
    mazedata >> row >> column;  // Pulls the size from the file
    GetExit(mazedata);          // Does the same for above, just for the Exit (Required in Class) 
    GetEntrance(mazedata);      // Does the same, just for the entrance (Required in Class)
    maze = new char*[row];      // First array of pointers for 2d array
    for (unsigned i; i<row;i++)
    {                           // Creates the second set of arrays 
        maze[i]=new char[column];
    }
    for (int y=0;y<column;y++)
    {                           // Keeping the maze inside boundries (step 1)
        for (int x=0;x<row;x++) // (Step 2)
        {
            maze[x][y]=mazedata.get(); // <--- Here is where my Seg Fault happens.
        }
    }

}
```

Here is what gdb tells me:

> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
>   0x08048fe9 in MazeClass::ReadMaze (this=0xbffff524, mazedata=...) at MazeClass.cpp:36
>   36                  maze[x][y]=mazedata.get();

Thank you ahead of time for all of the help.

Now that my code is fixed by a silly mistake, I am now able to move on to the next problem:

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/athetius/projects/code/netbeans/OLA4/a.out 
Please Enter Data Filename: MyMaze2.dat


**************12142*********** ***12142*
*            12142***** *     *  12142 *
*           12142 ************  12142***
***   *    12142           ****12142****
*         12142               12142    *
*    ****12142*****   ** *   12142     *
*       12142        *      12142 * *  *
*      12142        *******12142***    *
*     12142*        ** ***12142*********
*    12142               12142          
*   12142  *************12142***       *
*  12142               12142   *****  **
**12142*************  12142 *          *
*12142       ******* 12142            **
12142***************12142
Program exited normally.
```

With the output of:
view MyMaze2.dat being:

```
************************* ****
*            ***** *     *   *
*            ************  ***
***   *               ********
*                            *
*    *********   ** *        *
*               *       * *  *
*              **********    *
*     *        ** ************
*                             
*     ****************       *
*                    *****  **
***************   *          *
*       *******             **
******************************
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the line `for (unsigned i; i<row;i++)` which starts your first `for` loop, you don't initialize `i`.  Try `unsigned i=0;`.  That may not fix everything, but its a start :)

Comment: Ha, that worked. I overlooked that, now though I am getting something funky.

Comment: You might have more luck if you started a new question.  When a question has zero responses, I think it attracts more people to it.  You may also want to post your code that actually prints the maze...  I'm glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 1):

The actual problem seems to be a few lines earlier in the code

`for (unsigned i; i<row;i++)`

What is the initial value for i here? Nothing?